# How to position two different columns in a single row at a specific position in mobile view?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following code and in mobile view it shows the image at the end after the paragraph as it's supposed to. But i want the image to be displayed after the sub-header just above the paragraph in mobile view. Tried flex and everything but the image is coming all the way on the top above the header. Is there a way that i can achieve this just with html and css.

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-6">
         <div> Some Image Here </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h1>Header Here</h1>
        <h3> Sub-Header Here </h3>
        <p> Paragraph Here </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

So if i view in mobile it should look like this

HEADER

SUB-HEADER

IMAGE

PARAGRAPH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to get what you want is to use separate columns. Float the columns on larger screens using the `float-*` classes and then `order-*` classes to change the order on mobile.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row d-md-block">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-6 float-left order-2 order-md-1">
            <div>Some Image Here </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 float-left order-1 order-md-2">
            <h1>Header Here</h1>
            <h3>Sub-Header Here </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 float-right order-3">
            <p>Paragraph Here </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/IHe5K4aDqH

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I was not aware of ordering the columns in such a clean way.I am playing around with it to get familiar. I got one question. I ran ur snippet and if i change the view port to tablets the image is coming on top of everything. How to fix that. Attached screenshot. 
http://tinypic.com/r/dc3oyr/9